# is this set countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=:\{(x,x)|x\in[0,1]\}\subset[0,1]\times[0,1]$

I see A as $A=\{(x,y)|x\in[0,1]|x=y\}$ so it is a straight line bounded by points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ if I understand this construction.

Is this set countable?

I could not find a suitable injective function from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ so I was thinking of taking other approach through countable unions.

Can we write $A$ as a countable union of points it contains
$A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{(x_{i},y_{i})|x_{i}\in[0,1]|x_{i}=y_{i}\}$
would that work?
How to show it is countable or show otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that there is an obvious bijection between $A$ and $[0,1]$. So the question is, is $[0,1]$ countable?

Comment: no, it is not because it is a subset of an uncountable set

Comment: @Heidi: But $\Bbb N$ is a subset of an uncountable set. Is $\Bbb N$ uncountable? What about $\varnothing$ or singletons?

Comment: hm $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, the empty set is also countable (strange, because it does not have any elements), I am not sure about singletons. I remember that [0,1] is uncountable

Comment: @Heidi: Being a subset of an uncountable set doesn't imply anything about cardinality (finite sets, including singletons are of course countable). However having an uncountable subset *does* imply that a set is uncountable. Which sets do you know are uncountable? Can you find an injection from one of them into $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes I know that, I mixed that up. Uncountable are $\mathbb{C}$,$\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$, Cantor set and so on.

Comment: @Heidi: Correct. The Cantor set. And where does the Cantor set live?

Comment: it is a subset of $[0,1]$. What the obvious bijection would be that you have mentioned in your hint?

Comment: @Heidi: Well, just look at the definition of $A$ until you figure it out. Then you'll smack yourself on the forehead and go "Oh! That **was** obvious!" :-)